# Why I get errorafter adding CORS for all origins

Tags: iis, cors

When I try to access to WEB API from client I get CORS errors.

So for this purpose I add in CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in IIS:

[image]

But after `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is added I get this error on client:

```
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/fridge/api/user/15' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.
```

Any idea how to fix error above?and why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

look like you added two header entries.

you could try to remove the WebApiConfig.cs or web.config cors entry.

another way is you could try to add the exact domain instead of *.

```
var CorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.example.com","", ""); config.EnableCors(CorsAttribute);
```

If you using webservice(.asmx) as API

Remove 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' details from either in Global.asax.cs file's begin_request function or in web.config.